# Multiple Dispatch not required value

Tags: python

I had a method like this on python:

```
def method(a, b, c: int=0):
    return a+b+c
```

When I called method(5,2) it returns me 7.

However when I want to use multiple dispatching:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(int, int, int)
def method(a, b, c=0):
    return a+b+c
```

method(5,2) understandably gives an error. Is there any way to make one of the values in dispatch not required like a ref statement on c#?

Comment: How does method(5,2) not return the error:  method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c' ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, it is

method(a, b, c: int=0)

Comment: That's what I thought; please edit your question to include this; and, to answer it, @dispatch deals with args with default values by specifying their names.

Comment: For reference-  "dispatch" is a function from a 3rdy party package: people are not obliged to know from which library you imported it.  The boiler plate for importing in Python is minimal and provides a _lot_ of context for human readers, please always include the import statements along with your code, so that they are complete examples, and mention which 3rdy party libs you are using. (there are _several_ projects that can provide a multi-dispatch behavior to Python - I had to google and compare docs to find you are likely using https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/ )

Comment: (That said, after re-checking, I think you may have thought that the "multiple-dispatch" tag was mapping to Python's "multipledispatch" project-  but that is not the case: the tag refers to the computational concept, not to an specific project in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (you need to specify the names of args with default values when using @dispatch).

```
@dispatch(int, int, c=int)
def method(a, b, c=0):
    return a+b+c

method(2,7)
# Out[58]: 9
```